# How to dynamically resize xib according to UITextView

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, autolayout

I am using auto layout.

- I am loading `UIView` from xib.
- All elements have static size except `UITextView`.
- I've disabled scroll on UITextView
- UITextView is filled with the text of different size on `ViewDidLoad()`. So it can be 1 line or 7 lines there for example.

I am loading this UIView with the following method:

```
fileprivate func setTableHeaderView() {
    guard let _headerView = UINib(nibName: "TableHeaderView",
                                 bundle: nil).instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil)[0] as? UIView else { return }

    tableView.tableHeaderView = UIView(frame:
        CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: tableView.frame.width, height: _headerView.frame.size.height))

    configureViewController() // here I set the text for UITextView
    tableView.tableHeaderView?.addSubview(_headerView)
}
```

When I load this `UIView` the height is always the same both before and after `layoutSubviews`. Actually the size always is equal to the initial size of the xib that is set in the *Size Inspector* of XCode.

I want to `UITextView` to fit the text size and to have different xib UIView size that will depend on the size of `UITextView` + all other elements + constraints.

I've tried different ways to implement this but but none did not help. What I've tried:

- to set constraints in different ways
- to call layoutSubviews() forcibly and check the size of the resulted UIView
- to check size of UIView after viewDidLayoutSubviews
- `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true` with `autoresizingMask = .flexibleHeight`

Is it possible to implement this idea in such way?

Comment: Do you need a UITextView? Do you need to have user input to it? If not you'd be better off using a UILabel for this.

Comment: @Fogmeister No I don't need exactly UITextView, do you think UILabel will help with UIView from xib resizing?

Comment: A UITextView is designed to scroll when the text it contains is too big. The size of the text view is independent of the size of the text inside it. With anUIlabel the intrinsic size of the label is the size of the text and it should resize your view.

Comment: @Fogmeister I've already disabled scroll on UITextView, so it work in the same way as UILabel in case of the intrinsic size

Comment: Hmm... I'd have to verify that. Not sure that's the case?

Comment: @Fogmeister I am actually not sure that it is possible to resize the xib size to fit its contents with auto layout

Comment: Ah... are you trying to resize the nib inside interface builder? Or when it's on a device running in the app?!

Comment: @Fogmeister I am trying to get dynamically sized UIView (depend on its contents) that is loading from xib

Comment: Yes. That is possible. What code are you using to load it?

Comment: @Fogmeister I've added the method to the description above

Comment: Try to set tableView like this tableView.tableHeaderView = _headerView

Comment: @iamirzhan this will not help, the problem is that the UIView always has the same height, that doesn't rely on its content. So when I set the `tableHeaderView` there is already a problem in the code

Comment: Try to use this code http://collindonnell.com/2015/09/29/dynamically-sized-table-view-header-or-footer-using-auto-layout/

Comment: @iamirzhan the last one works (link you've provided). Thanks!

Comment: Ok, I have converted it to answer for other viewers. Please, accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to override viewDidLayoutSubviewsMethod

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

    // Dynamic sizing for the header view
    if let headerView = tableView.tableHeaderView {
        let height = headerView.systemLayoutSizeFittingSize(UILayoutFittingCompressedSize).height
        var headerFrame = headerView.frame

        // If we don't have this check, viewDidLayoutSubviews() will get
        // repeatedly, causing the app to hang.
        if height != headerFrame.size.height {
            headerFrame.size.height = height
            headerView.frame = headerFrame
            tableView.tableHeaderView = headerView
        }
    }
}
```